# React Native Prettier is formatting wrong. How do we fix it

Tags: react-native, formatting, prettier

I am using prettier in React Native to format the code on save however it format wrong can someone tell me how to fix this. On long lines it doe the follow

```
if (JSON.stringify(eachVal.Children) 
!== JSON.stringify([])) {
                parent.push(eachVal.UUID);
                return finding_uuid(eachVal.Children);
              }
```

The code works correctly without issues but it looks bad as it does not look as if formatted correctly How do it fix it so that it looks more like the follow below

```
if (JSON.stringify(eachVal.Children) !== JSON.stringify([])) {
                parent.push(eachVal.UUID);
                return finding_uuid(eachVal.Children);
              }
```